# Why can't I reproduce my results in keras using random seed?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I was doing a task using RNN to predict a time series movement.

I want to make my results reproducible. So I strictly followed this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras

My code are as follows:

```
# Seed value
# Apparently you may use different seed values at each stage
seed_value= 0

# 1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)

# 2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

# 3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)

tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)

tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)

# 5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session

# for later versions:
session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

However, every time I ran my codes, I still got a different result, what could the reasons be?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic (please read the [rules](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Consider asking programming questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ArayKarjauv I don't think this is a programming question, but OK.

Comment: FYI If using GPU, non-random reproducibility is more complicated than that because of random results ordering.